# I'm having large back-end file in php? Then how to go the last line of visual studio code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having large files in my project, every time scrolling is taking time. Can any one suggest shortcut to go end of the file. so that I can add new code there?

Answer (score 1):

If you use CTRL + END it will go at the end of the file it should work on all editors.
You can change the shortcut in Visual Studio Code in File > Settings > Keyboard shortcut
The name of the shortcut is `cursorBottom`

Comment: Ctrl + Left  Arrow is not working. I'm using UBUNTU 16

Comment: Your welcome don't forget to validate the answer if you think it's resolved you question :)